# DVD drive disappears if I insert a disc, but will read the same disc if it was there at boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, dvd

I have a very odd problem.

If I insert a disc in my dvd burner that is blank, I can burn it.

If I insert a disc that has info on it, while Windows 7 64 bit, ultimate is on, it will disconnect the drive.

If I leave the disc in, and reboot, it will be able to read that same disc until I eject and reinsert, at which point, it does back to issue 2.

What can I do to fix this?

Computer Specs

I7-4770k
Asus Sabertooth Z87
4x8GB 1866mhz DDR3
MSI GTX 770 Lightning

All Latest drivers and Bioses as per Nvidia and Asus/Intel website

Comment: disable AutoPlay completly and re-test  http://www.winhelp.us/configure-autoplay-in-windows.html (1/2 way down the page)

Comment: did not change anything

Comment: ahh thanks for checking anyway. I dont know what else really. you could check all your "startup" type items see if there are any CD interceptor type programs installed, like "directCD" type.  Rarely some of the devices that turn a CD into a R/W device using R/W media and RAMcd can cause an issue. Use autoruns, or hijack-this, and a bit of knowlege ,  at the desperate end of things the "upper filter" and "lower Filter" things, usually would not cause this type of issue, but are inbetweeners.

Comment: there was only the upper filter, and it has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

Boot into safe mode, then try again, if it does the same, check to make sure drivers are up to date, if they are, try rolling them back to the last update. If issue continues test on another computer, if issue does not persist, it is not a hardware problem withe the drive, if it does, then the drive itself is the issue.

It would also help to post your computer specs

Comment: Alright, so I moved the DVD unit to another computer, the symptoms did not transfer, so the drive is good.

This is a brand new computer, so I do not have any drivers to roll back too.

I7-4770k
Asus Sabertooth Z87
4x8GB 1866mhz DDR3
MSI GTX 770 Lightning.0

Using the latest bios and drivers as per Nvidia and Asus website.

Comment: Can you try starting up via a linux dsitro installed on a flash drive and then attempt using the disc drive with linux running, see if is simply issue within windows, or the hardware of the tower somewhere.

Comment: booted into Ubuntu, everything works like it should. It is only limited to Windows.

Next step?

Comment: have you done the Safe mode testing yet?  what are the results?  Which one of your port things is it on?

Comment: Safe mode results in the same problems. I have moved the drive from different sata ports. I found that if I use the AsMedia ports the drive functions like it should, but if I use the Intel Ports, it presents the issues in windows only.

I have also done a fresh install to remove the possibility of software interfering with it. It seems that in windows, the Intel Sata drivers, whether intel or windows, has a bug with the ATAPI commands, which would explain why it works if it booted with the disc in, but not if you change disc.

Every time there is a driver update I will report back.

Comment: weird, I had similar problems with raid controller not coping with my dvd and the "other"controller wouldnt either, but the intel it was ok.  WHAAAT do i gotta buy another computer to get a CD/DVD in somewhere :-)     I hope to have a upgrade like yours , but then remembering all the juggling.  luckily I was able to stabalise it all with the data held to the side while playing musical port.

Comment: what if there is some bios (or udfi) setting in there hidden in the dark recesses of its mind that has some compatability settings?  They have had settings in some bioses before that was oddly named and provided for the compatabilty to Atapi.  also way back there were various "fixes" for atapi, unbelieveable to me that they dont have these more simpler things working with ease.

Comment: Ok so the problem is windows only, and you can't update or rollback any drivers, it's a bit on the broad side but you could try reinstalling windows if there is nothing of importance.

EDIT: Just noticed you said you did that already, strange.